# Why would Mod_Rewrite only execute directives in the .htaccess folder of the deepest folder in the URL path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am running XAMPP on a Windows 7 machine.  I have enabled Mod_Rewrite in my Apache 2.4.10 installation.  And I have placed .htaccess files at:

- /.htaccess
- /category/.htaccess
- /category/subcat/.htaccess
- /product/.htaccess

On every server where I've used Mod_Rewite in the past, if I requested /category/subcat/some-file.html, it would

- Evaluate all rules in the .htaccess located in the deepest folder referenced in the URL path if one exists (i.e. /category/subcat/.htaccess).
- If the requested URL did NOT match any rules in the /category/subcat/.htaccess file, it would move up a directory and evaluate the rules in /category/.htaccess.
- If the requested URL did not match any rules in that /category/.htaccess file then it would move up to the document root and evaluate the rules in the /.htaccess if it exists.

For some strange reason my configuration is preventing this bottom up evaluation from happening.

When a URL is requested on my installation, it ONLY evaluates rules in the .htaccess located in the deepest folder referenced in the URL path.  If no matches are found, it never checks the parent directory, grandparent directory, etc. for a .htaccess file to evaluate.

For example...

If I request localhost/some-file.html then it ONLY evaluates rules in the /.htaccess file.  If it finds a match then it redirects as specified.  If not it stops as I would expect.

However, if I request localhost/category/some-file.html then it ONLY evaluates rules in the /category/.htaccess file.  If it finds a match then it redirects as specified.  If no match is found in /category/.htaccess, it never evaluates the rules in /.htaccess.

Similarly, if I request localhost/category/subcat/some-file.html then it ONLY evaluates rules in the /category/subcat/.htaccess file.  If it finds a match then it redirects as specified.  If no match is found in /category/subcat/.htaccess, it never pops up a level to evaluates the rules in the /category/.htaccess file.

In my httpd.conf I have:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also jacked up the logging to wide open so that I could see exactly what was happening with the following in the httpd.conf:

```
LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8
```

Any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default, *only* the mod_rewrite rules that are in the per-directory context are evaluated. Any rules in the parent directories are ignored unless you explicitly use the `Inherit` rewrite option.

[In apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> This forces the current configuration to inherit the configuration of the parent. In per-virtual-server context, this means that the maps, conditions and rules of the main server are inherited. In per-directory context this means that conditions and rules of the parent directory's .htaccess configuration are inherited.
>
> **Rules inherited from the parent scope are applied after rules specified in the child scope.**

However, in apache 2.4, you have several kinds of inheritance. Along with being able to inherit from a parent, [there's an `InheritDown` option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions):

> If this option is enabled, all child configurations will inherit the configuration of the current configuration. It is equivalent to specifying `RewriteOptions Inherit` in all child configurations. See the Inherit option for more details on how the parent-child relationships are handled.
>   Available in Apache HTTP Server 2.4.8 and later.

So it's possible that you have been using apache 2.4.8 this whole time with an `InheritDown` option turn on in the server or vhost config. This is **not** the way apache ships by default.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I didn't mean to imply that I have been using Apache 2.4.8 in the past and witnessed this behavior.  In the past I've likely been using an older version or a version that was already configured by my clients or their hosting companies with the correct type of inheritance (I do SEO consulting).  
    
I've used several versions of XAMPP over the years to develop web pages, but this is the first time I've used it on my local box to write and test redirects.  I would normally do this on my client's test servers which would already be configured.

Comment: The type of automatic inheritance that you describe wasn't part of apache's mod_rewrite until 2.4.8